# Open URL in Chrome & save its source code using Command prompt

Tags: google-chrome

I am having a hard time to find how to save the page as html or .txt using command line in Chrome Browser,

This is what I've done so far,

```
C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --new-window
http://google.com
```

This command will open a new window of Chrome browser and visit google.com but i couldn't be able to figure our how can i save google.com as html or as txt file ,
is there anyway to do so using command prompt ?

Comment: My strategy would be to specify a dummy user data dir (using the `--user-data-dir` flag--see http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html) and then copy the youngest html file from the Temp directory to whichever destination you choose. You'd probably want to create & destroy the dummy data dir as part of each run of the command.

Comment: Perhaps used in conjunction with the `--record-mode` flag, which "saves *everything* to the cache"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot perform the task you describe manually, but you can perform it using WebDriver automation.

Chrome can be remote controlled using an API called [WebDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) (part of  Selenium 2 automating suite). WebDrive has bindings for various programming languages, including e.g. JavaScript and Python.

Here is example code for [Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (not tested):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
html = driver.page_source
f = open("myhtml", "wt")
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

[Orignal example](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: This is working much more slowly than actually doing it in chrome for http://www.notalwaysright.com/page/1

Comment: This should be marked the right answer. It's the one solution that actually works and is robust. It's just a shame you have to write a script rather than just invoke a single command.

Comment: And trying to use Chromium's new headless feature involves cloning a 6gb repo and compiling, as far as I can tell. No thanks.

Comment: What if I also want to store all images, JS, CSS files that are needed to render the page? Just like you are presing CTRL+S to save the page to read offline.

Comment: This post is 10 years old but the solution is still working fine. Here is an updated link for the code example: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: Thank you. Updated the link. I am 10 years older as well :(

Answer (score 9):

Do you really need to open Google Chrome? You can get the page source using Wget (available for UNIX systems or for Windows [in this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget)). Once installed, just use the following command:

```
wget http://google.com -O yourfilename.html
```

And this should be all :) I don't think there's a way to tell Chrome to download the HTML from the command line though :(

**UPDATE:** There's a repo on GitHub called [chrome-cli](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli#) that allows the user to control Chrome from the command line. Downside is that it only works on Mac OS X.

Comment: I am just wondering, what possible reason can be for this? If you download source code...it's just source code. Maximum, it can be adjusted to chrome user-agent, which also can be emulated with other tools

Comment: @Tigra The source code for many web pages is *very* different depending on the user who is currently logged in :-).

Comment: The question is old. Anyway, as I told : source code is source code. Logged in user is not magic.  It is response to the provided cookies.  Which also can be passed via curl.

Comment: `wget` won't help you when the page contains HTML generated by javascript.

Answer (score 7):

I created a small script to do perform exactly this task: https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as . See the demo gif in the README.

It *automates* the keyboard actions you would otherwise perform to save the page manually (literally sends those key signals to OS). As a side effect of it being used in another project of mine, it's been tested on various linux flavors: Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, etc - and works fine on all of them. It probably won't work (at least without modifications) on Mac, and certainly not on Windows.

Comment: Good work. For anyone wondering - this works by invoking the google-chrome binary, then uses `xdotool` to send keystrokes: https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as/blob/master/save_page_as

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --headless --dump-dom --enable-logging --disable-gpu https://www.google.com >c:\yourpath\yourfile.html
```