# Problem http403 error when accessing api through a python3 script using request library but not when accessing through browser

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I am having a problem when I am trying to access an API there is no documentation and it is not supported officially.

The thing is if I put the API link into my various browsers it works fine but when I try to access it through my python script I get a 403 error. It sends back a 200 ok response when I put in chrome browser.

I am assuming it is not Authentication or Cookies/Session Data because it works through various different browsers and I have experimented deleting cookies and signing out of the website etc. all seems to be working.

I am also assuming its not IP Blocking or Rate Limiting because its a singular request and from the same IP it seems to work fine.

I may be assuming wrongly though.

The `User-Agent` header must be the problem I tried changing the user agent and it didn't work. I tried changing various header data so its the same as my chrome browser but nothing seems to work. I have scoured the internet and stack overflow all day and can't find a solution

My python script:

```
import requests, json


data = "data"

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Cookie': '__cflb=02DiuFQAkRrzD1P1mdkJhfdTc9AmTWwYjJGtpDcTftSd2; X-Mapping-Server=s7; cf_clearance=I2RZ8gC2GNXzVT0nf_bcKUQEtU5oGRrFq6Eq1OjR_Xs-1696873939-0-1-5622ec48.635f2445.c3629c20-0.2.1696873939',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


# API endpoint
endpoint = f"http://link-to-api/{data}/

# Send an HTTP GET request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(api_endpoint_url, headers=headers) 

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json() 


    print(f"Response code: {response.status_code}")
    print(data)
else:
    print(f"{response.status_code} Error: {response.reason}")
```

Expected Output: PRINTS data from the API

Actual Output: 403 Error: Forbidden

So does anyone know why I am getting a 403 error and how to get around it so I can access this API from my python script. If there is a problem because I need to authenticate it or anything do share.

EDIT: Perhaps it is something to do with HTTP and HTTPS?

EDIT 2: Changed to make more generic also I found out after reverse engineering the API and some research my target api uses tls ja3 fingerprinting which I got around by using curl_cffi python module to spoof my ja3 fingerprint to a chrome browser.

Comment: Even though you set a real user-agent in the headers, some websites are still able to detect that the request is coming from a robot script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323476/open-url-in-chrome-save-its-source-code-using-command-prompt Use selenium to get the page and save it.

Answer (score 0):

What is is api.tracker.gg ?
You will need to recheck the documentation.

For Path Of Exile, their web site has a user code, POESESSID. This is found by going into developer mode in the browser.

This is then used in the header of the python or lua http request.

May I suggest that there is something the same happening here ?

And the cookie you supply, may well expire or be attached to the session in the browser, so is rejected for the python http request.

Edit:

[Open URL in Chrome & save its source code using Command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323476/open-url-in-chrome-save-its-source-code-using-command-prompt)

Use selenium to drive chrome and save the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I contacted the site admin and they don't offer the API because of legal reasons from the game developer so there is no documentation and no point using and I will look for alternative APIs now.